# Dataframe has correct number of rows, but the CSV does not (df.to_csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I've correctly created a dataframe from a for loop and I know how to save the df as a CSV. The dataframe is 7 rows (including row for headers) x 4 col. But, the CSV is only one row (x 28 columns).

I'm not sure how to make my CSV have the same shape/look as the df.

Here's my code:

```
filename = (r'~/Downloads/try_data1.csv')

raw_data = []

for loop: 
    box = np.where(stuff)[0] 
    binaries = np.where(stuff)[0]
    candidates = np.where(stuff)[0]
    singles = np.where(stuff)[0]

    raw_data.append({'range': ['%s to %s' % (i, i+delta)], 'binaries': [len(binaries)], 'candidates': [len(candidates)],'singles': [len(singles)]})

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ["range", "binaries", "candidates", "singles"])

#I believe everything is good until here when
#I change the df to csv

df.to_csv(filename, line_terminator=',', index=False, header=True)
```

My df:

```
df
Out: 
            range binaries candidates singles
0  [-1.0 to -0.5]      [1]        [0]     [2]
1   [-0.5 to 0.0]      [4]        [0]    [34]
2    [0.0 to 0.5]      [1]        [0]    [11]
3    [0.5 to 1.0]      [2]        [1]    [10]
4    [1.0 to 1.5]      [4]        [2]     [5]
5    [1.5 to 2.0]      [1]        [3]    [12]
```

When I open my CSV file in Excel it looks like:

```
range   binaries    candidates  singles ['-1.0 to -0.5'] [1] [0] [2]    ['-0.5 to 0.0'] [4] [0] [34].. etc
```

Comment: `line_terminator=','` Thats the same as the default separator. How do you expect to tell the difference between a field and a new line?

Comment: I removed it and it fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the `line_terminator` the same as the `separator`, because it's impossible to distinguish a new line from a new field:

```
### Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['11111', '22222', '33333'],
                   'B': ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc']})

df.to_csv()
',A,B\r\n0,11111,aaaaa\r\n1,22222,bbbbb\r\n2,33333,ccccc\r\n'
#        \-----------/                       \---------/                   
#        Lines separated                  Fields separated
#       by \r\n terminator                  by , separator
```

When they become the same there's a clear problem

```
df.to_csv(line_terminator=',')
',A,B,0,11111,aaaaa,1,22222,bbbbb,2,33333,ccccc,'
#    |                                   |
#    |------ These look identical ------ |
```

Comment: i like the illustration :)